# Cross-Origin Request Blocked .net and react only for POST but works for get

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, .net-5, http-status-code-500

As the title says, everything works fine for a GET request but it doesn't work for POST.

this is my ConfigureServices

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {options.AddPolicy(name: policyName, builder =>
                              { builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                                  .WithMethods("POST","GET").
                                  AllowAnyHeader();}); 
        });
```

This is configure

```
 app.UseCors(policyName);
```

This is the

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
```

fetch('https://localhost:44353/api/User/').then(res=>{return res.json()

}).then((data)=>{console.log(data)})

},[]);
And this is the code for POST

```
const handleSubmit = async(event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const pass = values.password;
const username=nom;
const user = { username,nom,pass, email, prenom,birthday,numero,adresse,cin,fiscale};
await fetch('https://localhost:44353/api/Client/Register', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(user)
}).then(() => {
  console.log('new user added');
})
```

};
For some reason the GET request response header looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRbKV.png)
while the POST request response header looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv7wJ.png)

this is error I'm getting in the console [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1StqD.png)

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44353/api/Client/Register. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 500.
And
Uncaught (in promise)
Object { message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: XMLHttpRequest, stack: ""

Comment: Can you paste the error you receive in console? The headers of the preflight response have been set correctly...

Comment: @NicolòTeseo I just did, its a normal cors error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/1StqD.png shows that the response is a 500 error.